# Reset / Reloading bash, completely (alias and function)

Tags: bash, unix, exec

I want to reset the shell, **as I log out / log in**, reloading aliases, functions, from scratch.

**But don't talk about `source ~/.bashrc` nor `. ~/.bashrc` !**

Why ? Because `source` or `.` just enrich the current shell, with new function(s), alias(es), and so on.

---

FYI, you can put this function in your bashrc :

```
function foo {
  echo "foo";
}
```

Then do `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc`. Yeah, **foo** is working. Then now, edityour `.bashrc`, and replace *foo* by *bar*, to have :

```
function bar {
  echo "bar";
}
```

You can now type foo, and saw **that the function foo is still working**, despite of it doesn't exist anymore in the `.bashrc` file. That's the point I wanted to show.

---

I tryed `exec bash;`, but it doesn'nt load the `.bashrc` file. And `exec bash;source ~/.bashrc;` obviously doesn't work, because `exec` kill the current process (`source` is never called).

Comment: have you tried bash --login ?

Comment: +1 @BigMike  this creates a new instance of bash, like you had just logged in.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Damn, you're good. Please write `bash --login` on a sweet answer @BigMike, and I can choose you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as OP wish

```
bash --login
```

NB: if you're running bash inside a terminal (xterm or alike), you need also to provide the `-ls` parameter (or equivalent) to the terminal. (e.g. `xterm -ls` )

Comment: Just one thing, each next login will run another bash process, while the old one is still running. Otherwise nice.

Comment: yes, because you're actually starting a new bash process. You can however kill the old one and detach, but usually this involves some shell trick.

Comment: So `exec bash --login` will kill the current bash, and start a new, right ? In order to avoid @Michal Trybus notice.

Comment: @Ash_ It does not kill the current bash in the technical sense: the current bash is replaced by the new one.  So in a colloquial sense it is killed.

Comment: With this one will lose track of running jobs until one exits the "recursive edit"

Answer (score 1):

Write the following script:

```
while true; do
    bash
    if [ $? -ne 123 ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Set the executable bit and set it as your shell.
Then add an alias in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias resetterm="exit 123"
```

This requires just one extra bash process running all the time. Each time you reset, a new bash will run, and the old process will end.

Comment: this is a nice one! On some sistem/with some shells I think you're not guarantee that initialization scripts would be executed.